# How to implement a user search system like Stack Overflow

Tags: php, url, search

When you look up a user on Stack Overflow, the url is something along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/users/6942666/eric-wiener. How does this work? Currently, I've figured out how to generate a user page using a get request in the URL, so it would look like http://myWebsite/generateUserPage.php?userId=1819238. However, I'm not sure how Stack Overflow is able to search for a user without making a get request. Are the pages pre-generated? That would seem like a waste of space. I've looked for solutions myself, but I'm not really sure where to start and the results aren't helping. If I could have some advice or pointers in the right direction, it would be really helpful. I am NOT asking for someone to write the code for me. I would rather write it myself. I just need some pointers in the right direction. If it helps, I'm using PHP and mySQL, but if you have advice in another language, it would work just as well.

Comment: What you're after is called [URL rewriting](http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/05/21/how-to-implement-url-routing-in-php/)

Comment: "without making a get request" — What makes you think there isn't a GET request? — http://i.imgur.com/GKrFKNv.png

Comment: You can rewrite the URL with .htaccess - which turns a URL like `/user.php=userID=1234` into `/user/1234`.

Comment: URL != filesystem path ... the URL is a lie.

Comment: Thanks so much @Pete ! Helped a lot.